# PostgreSQL find entries where timestamp differences are within range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a session_id, user_id, start_time, and value

Technically, a user should get a new session_id every 30 minutes, so there should never be a case where 2 entries have the same user_id but their start times are within 30 minutes of eachother.

How do I run a query to look for these error cases?
I did something like this to see some of the time differences for entries for a given user:

```
select t1.start_time - t2.start_time
from user_sessions as t1 inner join
     user_sesssions as t2
     on t1.user_id = 1 and t2.user_id = 1
```

I know that I'm looking for cases where:

```
((t1.start_time-t2.start_time) < 60*30*1000000 and (t1.start_time-t2.start_time) > 0) and t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

I'm just not sure how to put the two pieces together into one query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t1.start_time - t2.start_time
from user_sessions t1 inner join
     user_sesssions t2
     on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
where (t1.start_time - t2.start_time) < 60*30*1000000 and 
      (t1.start_time - t2.start_time) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LAG() OVER()` allows a simple way to calculate the time difference between rows:

```
SELECT
       user_id, previous_start, start_time, minutes_diff
FROM (
     SELECT
        user_id
      , LAG(start_time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_time) previous_start
      , EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM
                start_time - lag(start_time) over(partition by user_id order by start_time)
               ) minutes_diff
     FROM user_sessions
     ) d
WHERE minutes_diff < 30
;
```